# Javascript onerror does not fire on image that throws 404

Tags: javascript, image, onerror

I have an image from a content provider that needs to be loaded or just replaced by the text.

Example:
http://content.etilize.com/Brand-Logo/Black.jpg

This is a brand image that because it doesn't exist for this brand, it gets replaced via headers (from what I understand). So actual error event of image not loading does not happen.

```html
<img src="http://content.etilize.com/Brand-Logo/Black.jpg" onerror="console.log('test')" />
```

Here is how the request looks like:

[image: Image throws 404, but still loads after. Onerror event not triggered]

So when I try to catch the not-loading 404 error, onerror does not trigger at all.

How can I capture this 404 status code?

Comment: It doesn't fire the error event in this case because the server returns valid image data (the "Image Not Available" image). The DOM doesn't know that the response was a 404, it only sees the image data it received and therefore fires the `load` event instead of the `error` event. I don't know if there's a solution for this.

Comment: @Lennholm I was working on an ajax loading of the image, this way I would get request response, but I need to figure out how to make it so I wouldn't create 2 requests for the image loading instead of one. Need more research for this. This also complicates things as I would need to add the provider to CORS rules.

Comment: AJAX is an option if the server allows CORS. You can avoid a second request by using the image data you get in the AJAX response. Use [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a URL string that represents the data and then set that string as the source for the image.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to make a request using `fetch`, and checks the response status. If the status is OK, you just can create an `img` tag.

Like this example:

```
fetch('http://content.etilize.com/Brand-Logo/Black.jpg')
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    // create an <img/> tag using res 
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log("Impossible to load image"))
```

Comment: Would this create 2 requests essentially? I would like to avoid having 2 requests.

Comment: Yeah! I tried to use the resource loadings (onerror and onload), but the `onerror` specifically does not indicate bad request :/, thus `onload` resource will be successful.

Comment: I might be able to avoid this debacle if the content provider will throw a true 404 response. I asked them already, they might have something in the works.